# In Sandi Metz's OO Design in Ruby book, what is the difference between modules and inheritance?

Tags: ruby

On page 153, she makes a distinction between `is-a` versus `behaves-like` differences. Inheritance corresponds to `is-a` whereas the modules correspond to `behaves-like`. But what is the real difference? Both techniques rely messages via automatic message delegation right?

In the example she uses in the Understanding Roles chapter, it seems like the main difference is that modules lend better to duck typing and are used to make seemingly unfamiliar entities fit into certain roles? What is a role exactly? Anything that is a say `Schedulable` needs to respond to the module's interface and so therefore can be substituted in any place where all that is expected is a `role` that responds to that interface.

Whereas in the inheritance chapter, Metz just seems to define a hierarchy without the same focus on duck typing. With her bikes example, she solves the problem of related types that share common behavior but have subclasses that have some specialization.

However, commonalities exist. Both still promote abstract behavior into the shared class or module. Both still have subclasses that implement the same interface that can be used for duck typing purposes. So what are the real differences?

There's a lot more emphasis on ducktyping in the modules section than the inheritance section. Why is this?

Comment: This just makes me want to go back and re-read this awesome book.

Answer (score 0):

There are several difference, but in some ways they behave the same. The main difference is that modules can be included ad-hoc and mixed and matched, whereas you only ever 'inherit' from a single class. But in the end, both mix-ins and inheritance are implemented the same: the module or class gets added to the ancestors chain, and is used to find methods when responding to messages. In the case of inheritance, the class you are defining is added to the end of the ancestors chain. Modules can be included in different places in the chain (usually just before the class you are extending) but once they are there, they behave the same.

Another difference is that inheritance more often modifies or defines initialization. (Although it is possible to do that with a module, it's rare that you see that). If you care about initial state of an object, you probably want to use inheritance.

As for duck-typing, modules are often thought of as akin to java interfaces with built-in implementation. In java, since everything is strongly typed, you must explicitly say if an object "quacks". Interfaces do that, and are the "acts-like" of have. Modules are the closest thing to that in ruby.

Generally speaking, modules tend to be easier to use because of their flexibility, but a module is much more abstract, and must have a greater separation of concerns than a base class.

Answer (score 0):

I look at it like this.  I am a person, then as a person I am a man.  My wife is also person, but then she is a women, yet we both play the role of a parent.  A parent is not a man or a women,  but a person who plays a particular role. So the code that defines that behavior can be put in a module and shared by both classes.

Most modern languages have the idea of extensions,  where common behavior can be added to an existing class.  There are more examples, but both Kotlin and Swift make use of this in their standard libraries,  where they add common behaviors to a number of classes by re-using code defined in one place.

Java also added this concept when they added default implementations for interfaces.